# Getting "Invalid datetime format" even when using format defined in Request

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datetime

In my Laravel app I have an "Event" model with two `date` columns. In the `EventRequest.php` file I have defined the rules as such:

```
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "date_start" => ["date_format:d-m-Y", "required"],
            "date_end" => ["date_format:d-m-Y", "required"],
            "status" => ["required", "string", "in:open,closed"],
            "location_name" => ["required", "string", "max:100"],
            "location_description" => ["required", "string", "max:750"],
        ];
    }
```

However, I am getting the following error when I try and create a new `Event` with the `date_start` and `date_end` values as e.g. `06-12-2040` and `07-12-2040`:

```
    "message": "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '06-12-2040' for column 'date_start' at row 1 (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `events` (`date_start`, `date_end`, `status`, `location_name`, `location_description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (06-12-2040, 07-12-2040, open, Test name 2, Test desc 2, 2023-03-24 22:53:16, 2023-03-24 22:53:16))",
```

Can anyone please help explain what I'm missing here? Aren't these the correct format?

Screenshot from Postman:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I thing date format `d-m-Y` is not accepted by database. Use `Y-m-d` instead.

Comment: Another idea: Old versions of mysql has problems to manage dates after 2038-01-19.

Comment: @Wiimm your first suggestion to change the format to `d-m-Y` does indeed solve the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Date saved to the database needs to be `Y-m-d` you are passing `d-m-Y`. If you parse it to a `Carbon` object before saving, `Laravel` knows how to serialize that to save correctly.

```
$data = $request->validated();

$data['date_start'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['date_start']);
$data['date_end'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data['date_end']);

$event = new Event();

$event->fill($data);

$event->save();
```

Alternatively use a more standard date format, using `Y-m-d` would probably work without any tweaks.